# How to create an html document from scratch using the HtmlAgility pack

Tags: .net, html-agility-pack, dom

I just wanted to create my own simple document using the agility pack so create a new HtmlDocument that contains just the basic container elements - i.e.

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

How can I do this from scratch without actually loading the htmldocument with anything.

Comment: You should also tag this with .net - and your first sentence seems incomplete. Without knowing the agility pack more than just qick-googling it a minute ago, I suppose you'll have to start with a minimal document.

Comment: I figured it out

`HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode htmlNode = htmlDocument.CreateElement("html");
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode headNOde = htmlDocument.CreateElement("head");
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode bodyNode = htmlDocument.CreateElement("body");
htmlNode.AppendChild(headNode);
htmlNode.AppendChild(bodyNode);
htmlDocument.DocumentNode.AppendChild(htmlNode);`

Comment: @Pittfall `DocumentNode` is null in this case.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Even easier:

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
var node = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<html><head></head><body></body></html>");
doc.DocumentNode.AppendChild(node);
```